# how to drawing in python tkinter.canvas video stream

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to solve a problem for days.
It's about a function:
a video stream is loaded and displayed in a python `tkinter.canvas`. that's ok - but I have a paint function to draw on the video stream.
How can I make the drawing stay permanent?

```
# Wiederholung
        def update(self):
            
            ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
           
            
            # Bildfolge neu anzeigen
            if ret:
               
               
                self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
                self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tkinter.NW)
                # Logo einblenden
                self.overlay_img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "logo.png")
                self.canvas.tag_raise( self.overlay_img)
                self.canvas.create_image(width -160 , 5, image=self.overlay_img, anchor=tkinter.NW)
                
               
             
            self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)


        def paint(self,event):
            global count
            
            if count == 10:
              count = 0
            
            count += 1
            dot_color = "yellow" #"red"
            
            x1, y1 = ( event.x - 10 ), ( event.y - 10 )
            x2, y2 = ( event.x + 10 ), ( event.y + 10 )
            self.canvas.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = dot_color)
            self.canvas.create_text(x1+10, y1+10, text=str(count))
```

The paint function in tkinter.vanvas is linked to the mouse click.
how is the drawn circle retained in the running stream?

RPI 4, Python 3.7

Sorry for my English, I'm from Germany

Answer (score 1):

You should not create new image items (logo and video frame) in each iteration since the new image item will have higher z-order than other created items in the canvas.

Create the image items once in `__init__()` instead and update the video frame inside `update()` which does not change the z-order of the image item:

```py
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    # image item for the video frame
    self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=None, anchor = tkinter.NW)

    # Logo
    self.overlay_img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
    self.canvas.create_image(width-160 , 5, image=self.overlay_img, anchor=tkinter.NW)
    ...
def update(self):
    ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()

    # Bildfolge neu anzeigen
    if ret:
        # update video frame
        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.image, image=self.photo)

    self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem appears to be here is the oval and the text are there, but hidden beneath the frame image. All you needs to do is bring those to front.

`canvas.tag_raise` method can be a solution for this situation.

In below example, for each canvas item a tag is assigned. You can assign multiple tags as well, if required.  The method `bring_to_front` is being called after every frame update which is using `tag_raise` function to bring the canvas items with the given tags on the top.

```
self.paint_oval_tag = "paint_oval_tag"
self.paint_text_tag = "paint_text_tag"
self.frame_logo_tag = "frame_logo_tag"
self.frame_image_tag = "frame_image_tag"


def update(self):
    
    ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
   
    
    # Bildfolge neu anzeigen
    if ret:

        # delete the existing image form the canvas, 
        # otherwise, it will run out of memorysoon
        self.canvas.delete(self.frame_image_tag)

        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tkinter.NW, tags=self.frame_image_tag)

        # call this method to bring other items to font
        self.bring_to_front()
     
    self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)

def bring_to_front(self):
    self.canvas.tag_raise(self.frame_logo_tag)
    self.canvas.tag_raise(self.paint_oval_tag)
    self.canvas.tag_raise(self.paint_text_tag)

# Call this method after creating the canvas
def show_logo(self):
    # Logo einblenden
    self.overlay_img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "logo.png")    
    self.canvas.create_image(width -160 , 5, image=self.overlay_img, anchor=tkinter.NW, tags=self.frame_logo_tag)


def paint(self,event):
    global count
    
    if count == 10:
      count = 0
    
    count += 1
    dot_color = "yellow" #"red"
    
    x1, y1 = ( event.x - 10 ), ( event.y - 10 )
    x2, y2 = ( event.x + 10 ), ( event.y + 10 )
    self.canvas.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = dot_color, tags=self.paint_oval_tag)
    self.canvas.create_text(x1+10, y1+10, text=str(count), tags=self.paint_text_tag)
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I'll try to implement that.

Comment: @acw1668's answer looks to be better than mine one.